# Table td causing error vaildation

Tags: php, html, html-table

js

```
function validateForm() {
  var questions = document.getElementsByClassName("question");

  formValid = true;

  for( var j=0; j < questions.length; j++ ) {
    if( !isOneInputChecked(questions[j], "radio") ) {
      formValid = false; 
    }
  }

  alert(formValid ? "Submission Succesfull!" : "Submission Failed!");

  return formValid;
}

function isOneInputChecked(sel) { 
  var inputs = sel.getElementsByTagName('input');

  for (var k=0; k<inputs.length; k++) {
    if( inputs[k].checked )
      return true;
  }  // End of the loop, return false return false;
}
```

index.php

```
 <div class="question">
     <p>First time visitor?:</p>
     <label>Yes</label>
      check here the td and td closing !!!!!!
     <?php for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){?><td><input type="radio" value="<?=$i?>"> <?=$i?> </td><?php } ?>
 </div>

 <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br/> </form> </body>
```

My intention is to make this quiz valid but once I put the td before
input, the validation won't work anymore, but I need the td to make PHP output loop, so what am I going to do? Can I somehow change js script to bypass the problem?

Comment: "i need the td to make php output loop": false assumption. You do not, in fact, need the `td`, and since it is outside of `tr`, it shouldn't be there.

Comment: so i dont need td ? but how i going to arrange the table design ?

Answer (score 0):

YOU FORGOT TO MAKE IT PART OF A TABLE
For the td tag to be valid you must put them in a specified table. Here is the revised PHP script and HTML

```
<div class="question">
     <p>First time visitor?:</p>
     <label>Yes</label>
      check here the td and td closing !!!!!!
    <table>
        <tr>
        <?php 
for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){
    echo "<td>" . "<input type='radio' value='" . $i . "'>" . "</td>";} ?>
        </tr>
    </table>

 </div>

 <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br/> </form>  </body>
```